# What is the standard way to check the dimensions of a numpy input?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, text-files

I have a series of text files of a certain format. For instance, `file.txt` looks like the following, with shape like 50 columns of letters, and 70 rows of text:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCCCCCC
DDDDDDDDDDDD
```

I would like to put the following into a numpy array, and do manipulations. This array will have certain dimensions. The shape is something like 50 columns of letters, 70 rows of text, e.g. shape (70,50). However, some text files are "missing letters". The files in question look like this

```
AAAAAAAAAAAA
BB BBBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCCCCCC
DDDDDD DDDDD
```

I would like to check if any "spaces" exist, and throw an error. Is there a standard method to do with with numpy arrays? Do I do this before or after inputting the texts into an array?

Can I do this with multiple files? That is, if I input 200 files, the end results is a numpy array shaped `(200,70,50)`.

Comment: Have you thought about how to read those data in the first place? The spaces might cause a problem already there.

Comment: @AndrasDeak That's exactly why I'm asking. If I simply load into an array, entries may be placed in strange places. However, if I do some sort of search algorithm first for "spaces", that could take forever.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to read in the whole file as a string, `with open(filename, 'r') as f: data = f.read()` and then check whether a space is in that string with `' ' in data`?

Comment: And what do you intend to do with files that have spaces? If you are going to discard, you should check for spaces before putting them in an array.

Comment: @Reti43 I was going to throw an error.

Comment: Does this mean if you want to read 200 files and you encounter a space in the 56th, the whole process will end, or you will still do something with the valid text files later on? One more question. Do you guarantee that all text files will have the same number of rows and columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets simulate your file with a list of text lines:

```
In [401]: txt="""\
AAAAAAAAAAAA
BB BBBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCCCCCC
DDDDDD DDDDD
"""

In [402]: txt=txt.splitlines()

In [403]: txt
Out[403]: ['AAAAAAAAAAAA', 'BB BBBBBBBBB', 'CCCCCCCCCCCC', 'DDDDDD DDDDD']
```

How are you loading this into an array?  Often we use `loadtxt`, but that is for columns of data

```
In [404]: np.loadtxt(txt,dtype=str)
Out[404]: 
array(['AAAAAAAAAAAA', 'BB', 'CCCCCCCCCCCC', 'DDDDDD'], 
      dtype='|S12')
```

No use.

Let's `split` on these lines

```
In [410]: [x.split() for x in txt]
Out[410]: [['AAAAAAAAAAAA'], ['BB', 'BBBBBBBBB'], ['CCCCCCCCCCCC'], ['DDDDDD', 'DDDDD']]
```

Lines with 'white space' turn into lists with more than 1 term

```
In [411]: [len(x.split())>1 for x in txt]
Out[411]: [False, True, False, True]
```

So 2 lines have errors.

I could turn `txt` into an array with a single letter per column by passing the strings through `list()`.  This gives `np.array` a list of lists, all the same length.  A blank/whitespace at the end of a line could cause problems.

```
In [414]: A=np.array([list(x) for x in txt])

In [415]: A
Out[415]: 
array([['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
       ['B', 'B', ' ', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
       ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
       ['D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', ' ', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D']], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

I could test this array for `' '` characters with something like:

```
In [418]: np.any(A==' ',axis=1)
Out[418]: array([False,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

If the lines vary in length, then this `array` will not be 2d.  It will instead be 1d containing lists.

---

As suggested in the comment I could make an array from whole strings, and use `view` to 'divide' them into characters.

`loadtxt` with a 'non-functioning' delimiter would create a 2d array like:

```
In [434]: np.array([[x] for x in txt])
Out[434]: 
array([['AAAAAAAAAAAA'],
       ['BB BBBBBBBBB'],
       ['CCCCCCCCCCCC'],
       ['DDDDDD DDDDD']], 
      dtype='|S12')
```

And then split it into characters:

```
In [435]: np.array([[x] for x in txt]).view('S1')
Out[435]: 
array([['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
       ['B', 'B', ' ', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
       ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
       ['D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', ' ', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D']], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

Comment: The delimiter argument to `loadtxt` can be used to avoid splitting on whitespace. `view` can then be used to see the array as individual bytes.
`A = np.loadtxt('text.txt', dtype='|S12', delimiter='\n').view('|S1').reshape(-1, 12)`

Answer (score 1):

For most of the work you don't need `numpy`. The below code reads the input file into a list, each element will be a line of the input file (with trailing newlines removed). Then it creates a list of the same length, each element signalling whether the given string is space-less. If any of these is `False`, then you have a problem, and you can treat this case as you wish. Otherwise the space-less entries are read into a string-type `numpy.ndarray`.

```
import numpy as np

#read data into list "lines"
with open('input.inp') as f:
    lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]

#check ones with spaces
nospaces = [not ' ' in line for line in lines]

#throw an error here if you will
if not all(nospaces):
    print('Uh-oh!')

#or just ignore the ones contaning a space and put the rest into an ndarray
goodlines = np.array(lines)[np.array(nospaces)] #the only numpy-specific part
```

Example `input.inp`:

```
asfasf asfasfsa
asffsafsafa
asfafsafs afa
faaffasaff
fasafasffas
afssfafs asafsas
```

Output:

```
In [1131]: run foo.py
Uh-oh!

In [1132]: lines
Out[1132]: 
['asfasf asfasfsa',
 'asffsafsafa',
 'asfafsafs afa',
 'faaffasaff',
 'fasafasffas',
 'afssfafs asafsas']

In [1133]: goodlines
Out[1133]: 
array(['asffsafsafa', 'faaffasaff', 'fasafasffas'], 
      dtype='|S16')
```

Note that the final output is of type "16-character string", since we first turned out list into an array and then threw out the unnecessary parts. With minor work you can tailor this solution to your taste, and your example also seems to suggest that your input lines are of the same length (in which case the resulting array would have optimal `dtype`).

Comment: Not entirely a constructive comment, but... `In [1131]`? What kind of session have you been running?

Comment: The `run foo.py` in line [1131] is a 'system' command (of sorts) used in `ipython`.  It runs the script in the main workspace, leaving variables for you to check.  It can be very convenient, but confusing for people without `ipython` experience.

Comment: I'm familiar with ipython, it's the number that was a shock to me.

Comment: @Reti43 haha, good point:) I have a (very bad) habit of very rarely turning my laptop off (using Ubuntu I can get away with it, present `uptime` is 41 days). And I also like to play around stuff for SO answers, *and* I do my research-related post-processing in python. So I tend to accumulate long `ipython` histories.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks, I haven't considered that that could be confusing. Do you think I should rephrase the output? I'm not sure how, unless I paste the contents of the script into ipython...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you just read the file first, check for spaces and if it passes your test, you can store it for the eventual array construction. It's pointless to manipulate it with additional instructions into an array if you're going to discard invalid data, or outright throw an error.

```
input_files = ['input0.txt', 'input1.txt', 'input2.txt']
valid_data = []

for i in input_files:
    with open(i, 'r') as f:
        data = f.read()
        if ' ' not in data:
            valid_data.append([list(s) for s in data.split('\n')])
        else:
            print 'Invalid data in file {}. File will be ignored.'.format(i)
result = np.array(valid_data)
```

The code prints a warning when an invalid file is encountered. If you really want throw an error, it will stop the whole process and no array will be constructed. To do this, simply substitute the printed warning message with

```
raise ValueError('Invalid data in file {}.'.format(i))
```

Please note that this code assumes all text files have the same number of rows and columns. If this may not be the case, clarify how you would like this to be handled.

---

A short explanation of how we store out strings in the `data` list.

If you have a list of lists and pass it to an array, it will create a 2D array of that list of lists. For example,

```
>>> data = [['A', 'A', 'A'], ['B', 'B', 'B']]
>>> np.array(data)
array([['A', 'A', 'A'],
       ['B', 'B', 'B']], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

Here, the list has as many members as our rows in a file and a sublist has the column data. So if we get a list of lists of lists, where we have a list of each file, when we pass it to the array, we will have the desired dimensions. In your example, for 200 files with 70 rows and 50 columns per file, we'll get (200, 70, 50).

When we read the contents of a file in one go, they will be in the form `'AAA\nBBB'`, so how can we turn that into `[['A', 'A', 'A'], ['B', 'B', 'B']]`?

```
>>> data = 'AAA\nBBB'
>>> data.split('\n')
['AAA', 'BBB']
>>> [list(s) for s in data.split('\n')]
[['A', 'A', 'A'], ['B', 'B', 'B']]
```